# jar file needs db folder next to it, so that the application runs, how can i bundle the folder using 'javapackager' or any other tool

Tags: java, deployment, jar, javafx

I developed an SE 8 application that uses derby db, when i package the application using javapackager tool, using this command: `javapackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile Fun-Money -srcdir dist -srcfiles Fun-Money.jar -appclass lite.money.ui.MainUI -name "Fun Money" -title "Fun Money" -vendor "Fun Money" -Bicon=icon1.ico`, the packager does a pretty good job packaging the application in folder(1), and installer(2). the problem is: so that the application runs I have to copy/paste a folder called **finance**: which is the **database** next to the jar in tha app folder. I zip that folder(1) and works fine. now the installer does not package that folder next to the jar, so when the user install the application using .exe, he MUST manually copy paste the db folder in `C:\Users\YOUR-NAME\AppData\Local\Fun Money\app`, you know like cracking a game .

How Can I use a javapackager to add that folder next to the jar in the app folder thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**: I run this command instead: `javapackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile Fun-Money -srcdir dist -srcfiles -appclass lite.money.ui.MainUI -name "Fun Money" -title "Fun Money" -vendor "Fun Money" -Bicon=icon1.ico` as you see I did not specify anything for -srcfiles, as a result, javapackager bundles ALL files in dist folder which is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html seems to be unprecise as it states:

```
-srcfiles files
    List of files in the directory specified by the -srcdir option. If omitted, all files in the directory (which is a mandatory argument in this case) will be used. Files in the list must be separated by spaces.
```

Instead, try to repeat the `-srcfiles` option for each file that must be packaged. For instance:

```
javapackager -deploy -native -outdir packages -outfile Fun-Money -srcdir dist -srcfiles Fun-Money.jar -srcfiles finance -appclass lite.money.ui.MainUI -name "Fun Money" -title "Fun Money" -vendor "Fun Money" -Bicon=icon1.ico
```

Comment: I solve it by omitting the name of the file **-srcfiles -appclass** instead of **-srcfiles Fun-Money.jar -appclass**. the packager then load all files in the directory which is exactly what I want.